# Проблема при установке tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, keras, tensorflow

Установил библиотеку keras (py -m pip install keras). При запуске кода

```
import keras.preprocessing.image
```

Выдавало ошибку, что не загружен модуль tensorflow. При попытке установки модуля tensorflow (той же командой) выдавало ошибку:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Нашел на форуме решение, ввел команду следующим образом:

```
 py -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

На картинке видно, что tensorflow вроде как поставился:
[image: На картинке видно, что tensorflow вроде как поставился]

Но при попытке запуска той же программы выдаётся ошибка:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-9ba3ce758875>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/untitled/test.py', wdir='C:/untitled')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/untitled/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keras.preprocessing.image
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Что говорит о том, что, вероятно, tensorflow поставился неправильно. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте виртуальное окружение. Например, [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/). Таким образом Вы не будете загаживать системный питон и избежите конфликтов. Это делать стоит на каждый Ваш проект.

1 . Создайте новое окружение

```
 conda create --name my-env python=3.8
```

2 . Установите [tf](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) и [keras](https://pypi.org/project/Keras/):

```
 pip install --upgrade pip
 pip install --upgrade tensorflow # возможно, стоит указать конкретную версию, например, 1.15
 pip install --upgrade keras
```

3 . Проверьте, что всё работает. Откройте интерпретатор и сделайте:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
```